# How to get variable of a clickable image called from database?

Tags: java, php, html, mysql

```
  Description  i am calling images from database , i want to click on  particular image to get detailed of that image which i had stored in table .
```

In   one table row i am printing all images and given onclick "alert("") here i am getting id of which image i clicked .So how to pass that   variable which i am getting while image clicked to other page (so that i can    call all details from that id).

```
 <html><body>
 echo"<table>";
 echo "<tr>";



 echo "<th>"; echo "<h1>";echo"Id";echo "</h1>";echo "</th>";



 echo "<th>"; echo "<h1>";echo"Logo of Websites";echo "</h1>";echo "</th>";

 echo "<th>"; echo "<h1>";echo"WebSite Name";echo "</h1>";echo "</th>";

 echo "<th>"; echo "<h1>";echo"WebSite Link";echo "</h1>";echo "</th>";

 echo "<th>"; echo "<h1>";echo"WebSite Rating";echo "</h1>";echo "</th>";



 echo "<th>"; echo "<h1>";echo"Rate Here";echo "</h1>";echo "</th>";



 echo"</tr>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($find_data)){

 echo"<tr>";

 echo"<td>"; echo $row["id"]; echo"</td>";
 ?><div name = "ashish"><?php
 $idd=$row["id"];?></div><?php
 $showLink=$row["game"];


 echo"<td>";?> <img src="images\logo\<?php echo $row["votted"];?>"     height="100px" weidth="60px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"    onClick="alert(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)"> <?php echo"</td>";

 echo"<td>"; echo $row["picture"]; echo"</td>";

 echo"<td>";?><a href="https://<?php echo $row["game"]?>"> <?php echo       $row["game"]; ?></a><?php  echo"</td>";

 echo"<td>"; echo "Total Rating -> ";echo $row["rating"]; echo "</br>";echo      "Total number of People Voted -> ";echo$row["hits"];
 echo"</td>";
 echo"<td>"; ?><form action='index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=47'    method ='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' ><input type='submit' value='Rate   Here !' name='rateus'/></form><?php echo"</td>";

echo "</tr>";

}
echo"</table>";
</body>

</html> 
  Description  i am calling
```

images from database ,
 i want to click on
 particular image to get detailed 
of that image which 
i had stored in table .

Answer (score 0):

try with simple anchor action, alter

```
 echo"<td>"; echo $row["picture"]; echo"</td>";
```

**TO**

```
  echo "<td><a href='viewpage.php?id=".$row['id']."'</a>", $row["picture"], "</td>";
```

and in **viewpage.php**

```
$imageId = $_GET['id'];
// Here select the details of image using $imageId and display it here.
```

Comment: Doing Same but able to retrieve that id ?

Comment: you can retrive the value of id, so make select query using that

Comment: while printing $id=$row['id'] , it will print 1 , and if i put that id where i am taking image than it will print id of that image which i clicked , so how to retrieve that id ?

Comment: yeah i had read that thanks but i am new in this coding , can u do favour to explain in brief .

Comment: see.. in the above code while clicking the image it will redirect to viewpage.php , so in viewpage.php you need to get the id and make the MYSQL select Query using that id so you can get all the details according to ID

Comment: $id1=$_GET['id'];

$sql1=mysqli_query($connection , "SELECT * FROM sitedetail WHERE id = $id1");


while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1)){

$id = $row['id'];

$name =$row['name'];

$usess =$row['usessfor'];

$detail =$row['detail'];

}

Comment: i had dne that but i am not getting id from clicked image

Comment: Hello , now i am getting id in link , but not able to get that id in $id1=$_GET["id"]; what should i do